# I have two dialogs, one with button and another with Edit control . how can i access one control from other

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

Please clear my doubt.

I Have two dialog boxed  Dialog box A and Dialog Box B.

and Dialog A contains a Combo Box Gender and and the Dialog Box B contains the Edit Filed.

Once User Select the Gender as Male. the Edit Field of the Dialog Box B has to be updated with Male in the edit control .

How it is going to be possible.

Please Kindly Help in doing this.

Comment: Your description implies that both dialogs are displayed at the same time.  Is that correct?

Comment: This is MFC 101. If you don't understand this then you are going to really struggle. I suggest that you read up on the subject rather than just asking others for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose both dialogs are created before this operation.

So in that case, add a class to dialogB object, and write a public method like below:

```
    void setEdit(CString gender)
    {
    GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1)->SetWindowText(gender);
    }
```

In dialog A class get object of dialogB and call the setEdit() method on ComboBox change event